# Accessing a database from a worker process

Tags: python, postgresql, redis, psycopg2

I'm trying to put jobs that need access to a database using Python, Redis and PostgreSQL. I'm doing the following:

1. Put jobs in a Redis queue using [RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/):

   ```
   def queue_data(self, json_data):
       Queue().enqueue(process_data, json.dumps(json_data))
   ```
2. In `process_data`, perform queries on a PostgreSQL database using psycopg2:

   ```
   def process_data(json_data):
       with psycopg2.connect("dbname=pgtest2db user=pgtest2user") as conn:
           with conn.cursor() as cursor:
               # I'm not actually doing this query, but you get the idea
               cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
       conn.close()
   ```

Obviously this is far from optimal, since each call to `process_data` is creating a new connection. What is the best practice to achieve this? Who should be responsible for managing a DB connection pool?

Note that I'm forcing myself not to use an ORM, since I'm doing this to teach myself and I'd like to understand these patterns from a more pure perspective.

## Edit

I ended up using a custom worker like this one:

```
import os
import node

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
from psycopg2.pool      import ThreadedConnectionPool

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
redis_conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)
pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(minconn = 1, maxconn = 10, dsn = "dbname=pgtest2db user=pgtest2user")

def process_data(json_data):
    dbconn = pool.getconn()
    result = perform_some_db_actions(dbconn, json_data)
    pool.putconn(dbconn)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(redis_conn):
        print "Setting up Redis"
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

Comment: Doesn't `psychopg2.pool` contain a connection pool implementation?

Comment: I definitely need a pool, but who manages it? I can't pass the cursor or the connection through the queue, since those values cannot be "pickled" i.e. represented in a serialised way.

Comment: The point of a pool is that you do not need to pickle it. You can simply ask for a "new" one and you will be given an existing one. However, it appears you do not just want to reuse the connections, but also the cursor state. Am I correct?

Comment: What python module are you using to interface with redis?

Comment: @jjanes sorry I missed that, I'm using [RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/)

Comment: @HansThen reusing the connection will do

Comment: I think that what you need is a singleton object. That way you can just access the same instance from each one of the workers then get the pool from there.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is too late, but everyone who is wondering how to use psycopg2 among with RQ (especially when you're getting SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac - just open connection *inside* worker (i.e task. It is better to create singleton instead of opening connection every time). Not before worker.work() function.